# Operator & on VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I'm not sure about how this operator works.

For example, if I had:

```
signal vector_a : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) :=(others => '0');

vector_a <= vector_a(3 downto 0) & '1';
```

Would the result be `"0 0 0 0 1"` or `"1 0 0 0 0"` ?

In case of using `3 to 0` instead of `3 downto 0`, would the result change?

Comment: `3 to 0` is a null array. I assume you meant `0 to 3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"&"` is the concatenate operator, and concatenates items from left to right.

So in your example, the result in `vector_a` would be `0 0 0 0 1`

Using a different range would make no difference, the result would still be `0 0 0 0 1` when printed left to right. But it would affect the indexed values.